# sf2 : Unknown "asset" function in "@Twig/Exception/exception_full.html.twig" at line 4

Tags: symfony, twig, assets, assetic

I'm using **Symfony 3.1**

I have this error when I run app_dev.php :

> Unknown "asset" function in "@Twig/Exception/exception_full.html.twig"
>   at line 4.

I already checked my config.yml, and it contains these values :

```
framework:
    assets: 
        base_path: ~
        ...
```

I don't know what to do... I hope someone can help me. Thank you !

**EDIT : *Problem solved*.** I had to remove custom twig filters in my config.yml... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set:

```
assets:  ~
```

Issue about same problem
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/17291

**Edit:**

Please also check that`s symfony assets component was installed.
The symfony/asset component is required, even in 3.0, by the FrameworkBundle

As you can see:

https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/master/composer.json

Another way run update symfony to latest version and update all depend

Comment: may I see symfony/asset & symfony/framework-bundle when i launch "composer show" ?

Comment: You cant see it, because its part of synfony